# Are automorphic forms eigenfunctions?

Tags: automorphic-forms

The Eisenstein series are eigenfunctions of the non-Euclidean Laplacian operator. Are automorphic forms in general by definition eigenfunctions of certain operators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no. :) It is true that the official literature on this may create a misleading impression, akin to saying that a `periodic function' on $\mathbb R$ must be an eigenfunction for $d^2/dx^2$. In the automorphic case, it is implicit that (most) discussions of "$\Gamma$-periodic functions'' really refer to *special* $\Gamma$-periodic functions, akin to exponentials (or sine and cosine) among periodic functions on the real line.

The difference in the situations is that the individual *special* periodic functions in the automorphic context are much subtler things than in the periodic-on-$\mathbb R$ context.

But, yes, in fact, the orthodox definition of automorphic form/function requires $\mathfrak z$-finiteness, where $\mathfrak z$ is the center of the enveloping algebra of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ of the real Lie group $G_\infty$ that is the archimedean points of the ambient algebraic group. This slightly evasive generalization of ``simultaneous eigenfunction for $\mathfrak z$'' allows finite linear combinations of eigenfunctions, as well as derivatives of Eisenstein series with regard to the spectral parameter `$s$'.

But, not, not everything in $L^2(\Gamma\backslash G)$, nor in $L^2(G_k\backslash G_{\mathbb A})$ is an eigenfunction for those operators.

The spectral decomposition theorem is that everything in $L^2$ is a superposition of eigenfunctions (meaning to not only use genuine $L^2$ eigenfunctions, but also non-$L^2$ eigenfunctions such as Eisenstein series).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, someone informed me that it is even misleading to say that Eisenstein series are "eigenfunctions" of the non-Euclidean Laplacian, since Eisenstein series are not in L$^2$.